# Ajax - Sending and Receiving

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 files, A .js and a .php. The .php connects to the MySQL DB and the .js is the front end of the system.
I'm in the middle of trying to set it up so it sends a hash key to the ajax which returns the correct data for the related person from the database.
So far it does work as it send the hash from the URL to the PHP file and returns back the data in the console log.

```
//AJAX Function
//Grabs Varibles from PHP

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

$(function() {
    $('.hashfield').text(hash)
});

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    url: "SelectFromSQL.php",
    //Sending URL password
    data:{ hash: hash, WorkingHash : "yes" },
    success: function(data){
      //Return of AJAX Data
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function() {   
        console.log("FAIL");    
    }
  })
```

This is within the .js file which sends the hash

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['WorkingHash'])){
     $hash = $_POST['hash'];

    function IDHASH($hash){
       echo $hash;
    }
    IDHASH($hash);
}

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT ID, CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country FROM customers WHERE ID=$hash";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["ID"] . "<br>"; 
        echo $row["CustomerName"] . "<br>"; 
        echo $row["ContactName"] . "<br>";
        echo $row["Address"] . "<br>";
        echo $row["City"] . "<br>";
        echo $row["PostalCode"] . "<br>";
        echo $row["Country"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

This is the .php file. I need to return the data from the database related to the correct customer ID.
All the data being echoed from the while loop will need it's own variably within a js format

My Goal is to retrieve each entry from the database

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["ID"] . "<br>"; 
    echo $row["CustomerName"] . "<br>"; 
    echo $row["ContactName"] . "<br>";
    echo $row["Address"] . "<br>";
    echo $row["City"] . "<br>";
    echo $row["PostalCode"] . "<br>";
    echo $row["Country"] . "<br>";
 }
 }

instead use

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 
 print_r(json_encode($row));
}
```

and in js 
   javacript

```
 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
async: false,
cache: false,
url: "SelectFromSQL.php",
//Sending URL password
data:{ hash: hash, WorkingHash : "yes" },
success: function(data){
  //Return of AJAX Data
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
//YOU CAN USE data.ID , data.CustomerName and so on
   },
   error:function() {   
     console.log("FAIL");    
    }
  })
```

Comment: I got the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Comment: I now have this return in the console log - 2{"ID":"2","CustomerName":"Cardinal","ContactName":"Tom B. Erichsen","Address":"Skagen 21","City":"Stavanger","PostalCode":"4006","Country":"Norway"}

Comment: sorry for late reply. what is that 2 in front of { are you printing any other thing before print_r ... and as i mentioned u can now use data.ID , data.CustomerName and so on.. data.ID is 2 and data.CustomerName is Cardinal

Comment: Hi, The 2 is the echo from hash, i have since removed this. I tried the data.ID ect and no luck, it just reports the above error

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

### Edit

instead of **return** data **echo** it like this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // echo the data instead of return
   echo json_encode($result->fetch_assoc());
}
```

To access the properties of the object you can in your success function do that :

```
success: function(data){
    // parse your data first
       data = JSON.parse(data);

      //Return of AJAX Data
        console.log(data.CustomerName);
        console.log(data.ContactName);
  // you can assign them to a variables if you want 
  var customerName =  data.CustomerName;
  var ccontactName =  data.CustomerName;       
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if returned I will still need to assign it to a JS variable

Comment: No you won't since you are using ajax. what error do you get?

Comment: I got the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" but I now have this return in the console log - 2{"ID":"2","CustomerName":"Cardinal","ContactName":"Tom B. Erichsen","Address":"Skagen 21","City":"Stavanger","PostalCode":"4006","Country":"Norway‌​"} so it is receiving the JSON.

Comment: so what problem are you facing now?

Comment: I need each value assigned to a variable to access within the page. For example I need to use the CustomerName ect

Comment: Thanks but i get the return "undefined" but it still list the log of data - 2{"ID":"2","CustomerName":"Cardinal","ContactName":"Tom B. Erichsen","Address":"Skagen 21","City":"Stavanger","PostalCode":"4006","Country":"Norway"}

Comment: Still no luck i'm afraid